# Find messages corresponding to a name in a tuple Python

Tags: python, function, tuples

I have a task where I read a file in a function which contains a chat log between different people. The chat looks like this:

```
Anna
Hello Everyone
Kalle
Hi there
Anna
Coffee break?
Pelle
Absolutely
Kalle
Sure
Anna
Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes
```

I created a function that creates tuples for the name and the corresponding message, two rows in one tuple. It looks like this:

```
[('Anna', 'Hello Everyone'), ('Kalle', 'Hi there'), ('Anna', 'Coffee break?'), 
('Pelle', 'Absolutely'), ('Kalle', 'Sure'), ('Anna', 'Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes')]
```

So, what I want to do now is to create another function that finds all the messages that belongs to e.g. Anna. So if I type "Anna" as input when I run the program, I want the function to find all the messages that Anna wrote and then the output should look like this:

```
[Anna] --> Hello Everyone
[Anna] --> Coffee break?
[Anna] --> Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this? I've tried different codes to find what I want in the tuple but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to narrow the focus of your question, as well as showing the code you tried and explaining exactly how it "didn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple loop?

```
l = [('Anna', 'Hello Everyone'), ('Kalle', 'Hi there'), ('Anna', 'Coffee break?'), 
('Pelle', 'Absolutely'), ('Kalle', 'Sure'), ('Anna', 'Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes')]

def find_by_name(name, l):
    for msg in l:
        if msg[0] == name:
            print(f"[{name}] --> {msg[1]}")

find_by_name('Anna', l)
```

Which gives:

```
[Anna] --> Hello Everyone
[Anna] --> Coffee break?
[Anna] --> Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward comprehension: iterate through the list pairs.  Filter for the messages in which the person is the name you want.

```
[msg for person, msg in l if person == name]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a program that asks for the users input, here's an option. All these answers are fairly similar so far.

You can loop through the tuples in the list and then you can index the tuples. If tpls is your list of (name,msg) pairs then `tpls[0]` will give you the first tuple. `tpls[0][0]` will give you the name in the first tuple and `tpls[0][1]` will give you the message in the first tuple.

```
def find_msg(tpls):
    name = input()
    for tpl in tpls:
        if tpl[0] == name:
            print("[{}] -->".format(name),tpl[1])

find_msg(tpls)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as well :)